Finding maximum and minimum value using Linear Algebra
I was trying to solve this problem:

Find the maximum and the minimum values of the expression $q(x, y) = 3x^2 + 4xy + 5y^2$ subject to the condition $x^2 + y^2 = 10$.

I am able to calculate the eigenvectors, eigenvalues and the diagonal matrix using orthonormal matrix.
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\text{eigenvalue} && 4 + \sqrt{5} & 4 - \sqrt{5} \\[4pt]
\text{eigenvector} && \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2} \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \\[4pt]
\text{orthonormal} && \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{4-\sqrt{5}}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-\sqrt{5}}} \end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5}}} \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5}}} \end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
$$
They are orthonormal, so we can use
$$
q(x,y) = 
\begin{bmatrix} x & y \end{bmatrix} 
U^\top D \,U 
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} 
$$
to represent the function. How can I calculate the max and min value with the given condition
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 10.
$$

Please use MathJax to typeset the math, and do not just link to a picture of the question.

You only need to calculate the eigenvalues:
$$\lambda_1 = 4+\sqrt 5, \: \lambda_2 = 4-\sqrt 5$$
With $w^T = (x\:\: y)^T$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 2 & 5\end{pmatrix}$, a simple calculation using the existence of a orthonormal diagonalization shows that
$$ \lambda_2||w||_2^2 \leq w^TAw \leq \lambda_1 ||w||_2^2$$
Hence, the minimum is $\boxed{(4-\sqrt 5)\cdot 10}$ and the maximum is $\boxed{(4+\sqrt 5)\cdot 10}$
Some additions referring to a comment:
Using normalized eigenvectors you get an orthogonal matrix $U$ ($U^T=U^{-1}$) with
$$U^TAU = \underbrace{\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}_{D}$$
Besides this, we have by definition $||w||_2^2 = x^2+y^2$.
Since $U$ is orthogonal, you have $||Uw||_2 =||U^Tw||_2 = ||w||_2$.
Now write:
$$w^TAw = w^TUU^TAUU^Tw \stackrel{v=U^Tw}{=}v^TDv= \lambda_1v_1^2 + \lambda_2v_2^2,$$
where $v_1,\, v_2$ are the components of the vector $v$.
Oviously, you have
$$\lambda_2\underbrace{(v_1^2 +v_2^2)}_{=||v||_2^2=||w||_2^2} \leq  w^TAw \leq \lambda_1(v_1^2 +v_2^2)$$
Now, you use the restriction $v_1^2+v_2^2=x^2+y^2=10$ and you are done.

where do we get 10 from, Can you explain? is it the restriction of x^2 + y^2 = 10? Why so?
and also explain this representation of       λ2||w||22≤wTAw≤λ1||w||22

@user1495080
I have added some clarification to my answer addressing your questions.

thanks alot, understood
